# Android studio 2.2.0-rc1 gradle plugin error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've just updated Android Studio to the version `2.2.0-rc1` android get error:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-rc1/gradle-2.2.0-rc1.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-rc1/gradle-2.2.0-rc1.jar

I've also checked if it exists in an `jcenter` repository and it returns error

> {
>     "errors" : [ {
>       "status" : 404,
>       "message" : "Could not find resource"
>     } ]
>   }

As I understand it's problem on `Android Studio` side, right?

Comment: I got the same problem here :(

Comment: got the same problem, and the accepted  answer no work for me.

Comment: Have you updated version to 2.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221529

The problem is already fixed (exactly: hour ago). Just for sure invalidate caches and restart android-studio.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it`s android studio bug. 
gradle-2.2.0-rc1.jar already exist at:

> {android_studio_directory}\gradle\m2repository\com\android\tools\build\gradle\2.2.0-rc1\gradle-2.2.0-rc1.jar

but sometimes android studio can`t find it there and try to download it from bintray, where it have not been uploaded.
File / Invalidate Caches/Restart fix it for me.