# Could not find gradle 2.2.0-rc1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

After updating to Android Studio 2.2 RC, it asked me to update gradle plugin to 2.2.0-rc1. When I update I get the following error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-rc1.
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-rc1/gradle-2.2.0-rc1.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.0-rc1/gradle-2.2.0-rc1.jar
Required by:
    :my_project:unspecified
```

Any clues on how I may fix it?

Comment: your internet connection is on or not ?

Comment: because studio is automatically downloading required files

Comment: Make sure you connected to *internet*. it will download files form *url*.

Comment: look..Internet connection is on downloading from bintray seems to be the problem

Comment: The Android folks probably haven't uploaded the artifact yet. You'll have to wait until they do.

Comment: I have the same error I have already posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39287116/android-studio-2-2-0-rc1-gradle-plugin-error and here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221529

Comment: You are not alone. This problem you have after 2.2 RC update.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221532

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221529

The problem is already fixed (exactly: hour ago). Just for sure rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Replace **jcenter()** instead of **mavenCentral()** in your project level **build.gradle** file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    }
}
```